# ASP.NET Profile Page Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am new to .NET framework and I want to create a profile page for each user to edit their own page. How do I make this edit page only available to the specific user? Is there a way to do this without me manually going into the code every time I have a new user sign up?

Comment: How are you keeping track of different users?

Comment: Well I have not started coding, this is more planning. I am not sure if I should use Entities or MS SQL instead to keep track of the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at [ASP .NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/yh26yfzy.aspx). Then you can lookup the user "profile" based on their Id to load the appropriate information.

Answer (score 1):

You start by ensuring that the page is only visible to authenticated users. You do this by setting the appropriate settings in web.config for the corresponding folder or file.

Once you've done that, this page should simply load details for the *current* user. All users would see the same page, but it's content would be populated by your code only for this current user.

There would therefore be no way for one user to display the contents for another user. The ID of the user being viewed/edited should definitely not be a query argument or anything like that.

Comment: Are you saying after authentication of general users(non-anonymous) e.g(user="?", user="*") is set up, the membership system takes care of itself in some sense?

Comment: No, your application would take care of it by displaying only information for the current user. What more do you need besides that?